# Page Albums App

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I've got an developper account, and a page with photo albums that I want to display on a website.

I'm trying to use [Facebook Album Browser](https://github.com/dejanstojanovic/Facebook-Album-Browser). The doc of this plugin says that I should create my on app to get an access token.
If I've understand correctly, I need a Page Access Token. But that's where I'm defently lost...

How to obtain it? There is no login action with this plugin, and I'll be the only one using this app. If I'm following the [Facebook Dev Doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/examples/?locale=en_US#screencast), it says that :

> You do not need to submit your app if it will only be used by you or by a reduced number of people. Any account listed in the Roles tab in your App Dashboard, such as admins, developers and testers, can access all permissions and generate a user or page access token.

I'm the admin for this app and the admin for the page.
Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

Comment: WARNING: you really should not use that plugin with an access token. the plugin suggests hardcoding the token, and tokens ALWAYS need to be kept secret. ALL tokens. hardcoding a page token in client code is really bad. you need to do that server side.

Comment: So this plugin shouldn't be used at all?? How can it be used server side with an apache2 php server?
I'm starting to think that I'll have to redo everything with php... ;(

Comment: that is what i am telling you ;) - don´t use the plugin, program your own solution with php (or whatever server language you are using).

Comment: ok! Got it! :D thanks a lot anyway, for your tuts.